Disable API authentication when using OpenAPI
I am using below spring and openAPI dependency:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

My Security config class is defined below:
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // ensure the passwords are encoded properly
        UserDetails userDetails = new User(userName, password, Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + ROLE)));
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "swagger.auth.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String regexPattern;
        if(swaggerAuthEnabled) {
            /* Desc: Below regex will hold true for :
             *        - pattern containing health in its resource
             *        - pattern if it not contains
             *           > /actuator/<something>
             *           > /v2/api-docs
             *           > /swagger-ui.html
             * */

            regexPattern = ".*(/health)|^(?!/v2/api-docs|.*/swagger\\-ui\\.html|.*/actuator/).*$";
        } else {
            regexPattern = ".*";
        }
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(regexPattern)
                                                       .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                   .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

I have added SecurityScheme of type: HTTP and scheme: BASIC
My objective is add authentication over swagger UI, which is working fine, but all my APIs are also now behind authentication due to which I am getting 401 error while accessing them through postman or other service.
I am pretty new to OpenAPI and seem to be lost by going through all other related solutions on stack overflow.
Thanks for the help!

If I understand your question right, the issue is that every request is now have to be authenticated .anyRequest().authenticated() and if you want to just allow any unauthenticated requests to any endpoint you have to change it to .anyRequest().permitAll()
Or if I don't :) - you can use authenticated request to your endpoints with Postman requests but you have to add Authorization header(header field in the form of Authorization: Basic , where  is the Base64 encoding of ID and password joined by a single colon : Wiki
.) or choose Auth type in Postman like Basic Auth and add you username and password there Postman doc.

The issue with removing .authenticated() is that it makes my swagger UI un-authenticated too. Let me summarise my requirement - I want my swagger UI to be authenticated but do not want my API endpoints to get behind any authentication.

I think the issue is beneath this part:  authorize.requestMatchers(regexPattern), you have to create RegexRequestMatcher regexRequestMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher(regexPattern, null); object and then pass it to .requestMatchers(regexRequestMatcher) and you code will be like this:
RegexRequestMatcher regexRequestMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher(regexPattern, null);
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers(regexRequestMatcher).authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build(); 

This approach work for me well in local test environment. PS: and as I said previously you have to allow all other requests: .anyRequest().permitAll(). Good day and happy testing :)
